# differences between convex functions

Tags: convex-analysis

Let S be the set of functions from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$ which can be expressed as a difference between two convex functions. Clearly S is closed under sum and difference, however I also suspect it is closed under product, integration (for functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$), inversion (for invertible functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$) and reciprocal (for non zero functions). Specifically I would like to show each of these:

Let $f,g \in S$, then
(1) $f*g \in S$
(2) if $n=1$ then $h(t) = \int_{0}^{t} f(x)dx \in S$
(3) if $f^{-1}$ exists then $f^{-1}\in S$
(4) if $\forall x, f(x)\neq 0$ then $1/f \in S$

However unlike the case of summation this is not as easy and I'm not sure how. Also I am not sure if all of them are even true.

**More broadly**
I would like to know if there is a name for this function space or if it is equivalent to some other space. What are the properties of this function space? Etc.

Comment: If $n=1$ then any $C^2$ function $f$ can be written as the difference of two convex functions.

Comment: could you prove this or provide a reference?

Comment: @mathew for the first convex function just integrate $|f''|$ twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In some literatures, the difference of two convex functions is called [DC function](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10107-018-1235-y). And it is also called [delta-convex functions](http://emis.impa.br/EMIS/journals/CMUC/pdf/cmuc0501/pavlic.pdf).

OP can find the first two properties from [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1021765131316). **The product and integration** can be refer to Proposition 2.1. **The reciprocal** can be found in Corollary of [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d105/19f66fef8d737bc9725fe017299decf85159.pdf?_ga=2.18358585.1046215122.1583471011-1087717429.1538456100) since constant function is also DC function.

For inverse of $h$, if $h(x) = f(x) - g(x)$, where $f, g$ is convex function, then
\begin{equation}
h^{-1}(y) = f^{-1}(t), \quad f^{-1}(t) = g^{-1}(t-y).
\end{equation}
The $g^{-1}$ is the inverse of convex function, which must be concave or convex, thus $h^{-1}$ is also a DC function. 
Here we need $f,g,h$ are all invertible.